# Predicate to check whether an element is behind another element in a list

Tags: prolog

Given is a List and two Elements. First I needed to check whether the two elements are part of the list.Afterwards, check whether an Element  `Elem2`
  comes after `Elem1` in the given List.
The predicate I am using is `weiterHinten` with 3 arguments.

For Example: check if c is after b in the list [a,c,b,a].

```
weiterHinten([H|T],H,B).
weiterHinten([H|T],A,B):-weiterHinten(T,A,B).

weiterHinten([a,c,b,a],b,c).
```

This goal would need to return false.I know, that after I find the Header of the list to be equals to `A` I would need to check if `B` is a member of the Tail of the List. If it is, it means that B is after `A` in the list, but I am unsure how to do this.

I tried:

```
weiterHinten([H|T],H,B):-member(B,T).
```

But whenever I was calling the goal it was always returning true for me no matter if `Elem2` was after `Elem1`

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. It might help if you specify what "it is not working this way" actually means; what it _is_ doing. Anyways, I tried to answer, let me know if it helped.

Comment: I meant that whenever I was calling the goal it was always  returning true for me no matter if Elem2 was after Elem1 in the List or not.                                      For example this goal:?- weiterHinten([a,c,b,a],b,c). returned to me true, even if it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the `weiterHinten([H|T],H,B).` rule out. This is a syntactic shortcut for `weiterHinten([H|T],H,B) :- true.` and that is nonsense.

This is working for me:

```
weiterHinten([H|T],H,B) :- member(B, T).
weiterHinten([H|T],A,B) :- weiterHinten(T,A,B).
```

The results are

```
| ?- weiterHinten([a,c,b,a],b,c).

no
| ?- weiterHinten([a,b,c,a],b,c).

true
```